# Not able to select dropdown value for Span Type using selenium C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to select particular value from drop-down menu but stuck at it, I can load dropdown but cant select anyone of them, here is below details

[image]

**Here is HTML details**
[image]

[image]

**C# code**

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("select2")).Click();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
driver.FindElement(By.Id("select2-alpaca4-container")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@id='select2-alpaca4-container']/..//*[text()='Normal User']")).Click();
```

I cannot use select since it has span as it is throwing error message
"Element should have been select but was span"
Can someone please provide me correct code here to select any one of the value

Comment: the below solution is working are not

Answer (score 1):

Try the below options:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("select2-alpaca4-container")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000L);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[contains(text(), 'Normal User')]")).click();
```

> OR

```
driver.findElement(By.id("select2-alpaca4-container")).click();  
Thread.sleep(3000L); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[contains(@title, 'Normal User')]")).click();
```

Comment: tried both but returns penQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException occurred
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//span[contains(@title, 'Normal User')]"}

Comment: have you clicked on "dropdown"